# Is it possible to use an apple 96W USB-C power adapter on an old MacBook Pro Retina 15" from mid 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, magsafe

In order to reduce the amount of power adapters, I would like to use an apple 96W USB-C power adapter on an old MacBook Pro Retina 15" from mid 2014, with an adapter cable USB-C to MagSafe.
Is this possible?
Are there any downsides, like too much power which results in faster loading which in turn produces more heat which in turn decreases battery lifespan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Apple sells only a USB-C to MagSafe 3 cable - not one for MagSafe 2. However, there are other companies who make and sell USB-C to MagSafe 2 adapters. Those would be third party ofcourse.

In terms of having a 96W USB-C adapter instead of for example the 87W or 61W USB-C adapter - that's not a problem. It is not so that the charger "pushes" 96W of power into the device causing it to overheat and destroy the battery. Instead the computer determines how large wattage it draws.